# What is the difference between "infrequent" and "rare"?

Tags: synonyms

I have come across the word *infrequent* in the patient information leaflet for Prozac.
When looking up the German translation of that word, I wondered what exactly is the difference between *infrequent* and *rare*?

Comment: `infrequent` indicated `what relationship between time and events. and `rare` just mean not too much.

Answer (score 5):

First, the definitions:

> **Infrequent**: [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/infrequent)
>
> Not occurring often; rare.

and

> **Rare**: [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rare)
>
> 1. (of an event, situation, or condition) not occurring very often.
>
>    1.1. (of a thing) not found in large numbers and so of interest or value.
>
>    1.2. Unusually good or remarkable.

From the definitions, we see that both *rare* and *frequent* can both refer to something that does not occur very often.

However, *rare* can also refer to something which does not exist in large numbers, such as works of art or certain species of creature.

So you can say that supernovae are *rare* or supernovae are *infrequent*. However, while you can say that the [Philippine Eagle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippine_eagle) is rare, you cannot say it is *infrequent*.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments by @JasonBassford, when used to express frequency, *rare* would be more appropriate in more extreme cases.

Comment: Based purely on those definitions, something **infrequent** doesn't occur *often* while something **rare** doesn't occur ***very*** *often*. Although synonymous, it could be argued (and it seems intuitive to me) that **rare** is the more extreme of the two.

Comment: I would argue against that: **infrequent** itself includes 'rare' as one of its definitions, therefore any extremity of frequency would be equal.

Comment: Something can be synonymous to something else while still having a different specific meaning. Among five different synonyms for example, frequently only one of them is the exact word you want to use. Dictionary definitions often provide synonyms; that doesn't mean that the synonyms are *identical* . . .

Comment: Shouldn't you be writing "From the definitions, we see that both rare and infrequent" instead of "From the definitions, we see that both rare and frequent".

Comment: @JasonBassford Actually, I think you've won me over. On reflection, I would also even agree with you that intuitively, I would use 'rare' as a more extreme case, but I guess my point was that one could not take that sense from the definitions, but more from real-world usage and experience.

Comment: Also worthy of note: "Infrequent" usually applies to *countable* things, while "rare" can be used for uncountable quantities. For example, you can say "Buses here are infrequent here" (buses are countable); and "Einsteinium is a rare element" (non-countable).